# perform operation on each element where class name === "select-multiple"

Tags: jquery

I would like to make all elements that have a css class of "select-multiple" implement the [chosen jquery plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

For some reason, I can only get the chosen plugin to work on elements by `id`. For example, this code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _searchFilterViewModel: SearchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel(allCountries);
    var _searchFilterForm = $("#find-vegan-products-page").find("form")[0];
    ko.applyBindings(_searchFilterViewModel, _searchFilterForm);
    $("#countries-select-box").chosen();
);
```

And this code does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _searchFilterViewModel: SearchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel(allCountries);
    var _searchFilterForm = $("#find-vegan-products-page").find("form")[0];
    ko.applyBindings(_searchFilterViewModel, _searchFilterForm);
    $('.select-multiple').each(function(i, obj) {
        obj[i].chosen();
    })
});
```

I'm using the wrong jQuery function aren't I? It seems that .each() gets every element inside the div of class `select-multiple`.

How do I loop through each element that IS implementing the `select-multiple` css class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` Try the below code

```
$('.select-multiple').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).chosen();
})
```